# db4o v8.1 Android Creating Database

Tags: android, storage, crud, offline, db4o

I am using db4o in my android application, and I seem to have some trouble in creating a database file. I am using this line of code below:

```
 ObjectContainer db = Db4oEmbedded.openFile(Db4oEmbedded.newConfiguration(), "Teams");
```

Which last I heard it would create a DB for you, and then you could manipulate it from there. Every time I run my app it crashes whenever I try to create the database called "Teams" it doesn't work. I have scoured the internet for a solution and I have not been able to find one.

I got to the root of the problem, it seems to be that

```
 Db40Embedded.newCOnfiguraiton() ///is what is causing the crash...
```

So I tried this:

```
        final EmbeddedConfiguration config = Db4oEmbedded.newConfiguration();// crashes here
        config.common().add(new AndroidSupport());

        db = Db4oEmbedded.openFile(config, dbPath);
```

But it still crashes on the same line... What could be wrong?

Can anyone show me how to please create a database file, **not** how to use db4o (CRUD operations). All I need is to know how and where to store and create a database file that works with db4o for my android application.... Thanks!

**I think I found what the problem is:**

http://mavistechchannel.wordpress.com/2011/11/18/db4o-at-honeycomb-and-ice-cream-sandwich/

Anyone know how to fix it?

I FIGURED IT OUT! LOOK BELOW!

Comment: Edit your question to include full exception stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out! To use the code above:

```
  final EmbeddedConfiguration config = Db4oEmbedded.newConfiguration();// crashes here
  config.common().add(new AndroidSupport());

  db = Db4oEmbedded.openFile(config, dbPath);
```

All you need to do is download the latest 8.1 version of db4o and place it in the **'libs'** folder, and you should add it to the **Android Private Libraries.** Once the jar is there, then you can run all the code you want related to db4o. Below is an example:

[image: Here is a simple example:]

Answer (score 0):

Didn't heard about or worked with this before, just trying to help you get out of this. Check [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-db4o-android-application) link. And, [this](http://community.versant.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.0/java/reference/Content/platform_specific_issues/android/getting_started.htm) may be the link you visited.

Not sure if this would help you or not.

Also, you can search here on their community: http://community.versant.com/Search.aspx?Search=android

Reference links:

https://gist.github.com/zapnap/737753

http://source.db4o.com/db4o/trunk/reference/CodeExamples/javaAppExamples/Android/src/com/db4odoc/android/Db4oExample.java

http://v4all123.blogspot.in/2013/12/using-db4o-in-android.html

Comment: I tried all the ways that your links gave me, but still none of them work..... I appreciate the help though.... :)

Comment: @Greg Aw... I was hoping, these links would definitely solve your problem...:(...So, what you can do is, post your full code and the error log you are getting.

Comment: That pretty much is my full code, all I am doing is creating a db onCreate of my activity.... No matter how simple I make it, it still crashes....